# jQuery list pop-out, make whole <li> clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a troubleshooting page for an internal system, part of this is having a bulletpointed list with some related issues, basically I've created some jQuery to push out the answer to the question, however this only works if you click from the text onwards, I want it to pop-out no matter where you click on the `<li>`.

Previously you could only click on the text but then I added a display:block to the span so it would pick up anywhere in or after the text, any ideas how I can make it select the whole `<li>` instead?

Thanks in advance.

```css
article {width:760px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;background-color:#F2F2F2;-webkit-border-radius:20px;-moz-border-radius:20px;border-radius:20px;padding:20px;}
article .footer {text-align:left;margin-top:20px;}
article .footer ul {margin:0;padding:0;}
article .footer ul li {list-style-type:none;}
article .footer ul li span, article .footer ul li span:before {display:block;}
article .footer ul li ul li {background-color:#fff;color:#000;padding:10px 15px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;letter-spacing:normal;margin-top:7px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;padding:10px;}
.lst {
 border: none;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: inherit;
 background: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 25px 80px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 5px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 outline: none;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 font-weight:bold;
 width:710px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 border-radius:5px;
}

.lst:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* List Blue */
.lst-b {background: #727272;color: #fff;}
.lst-b:hover {background: #0066CC;}
.lst-b:active {background: #004c99; top: 2px;}
.lst-b:before {position: absolute;height: 100%; left: 0;top: 0; line-height: 1.8; font-size: 140%;width: 25px;text-align:center;}

/* List Blue A */
.lst-ba {padding: 10px 10px 10px 33px;}
.lst-ba:before {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);}
.icon-go:before {font-family:FontAwesome;font-weight:100;content: "\f059";}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article><div class="footer">
  <h2>Related issues</h2>
  <ul id="expand">
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go"><span>Lost/forgotten my User ID</span>
    <ul>
     <li>If you have lost your User ID you need to contact your local administrator, this is usually the person who set up your account.  If you don't have a local administrator or don't know who it is please <a href="#">Contact us</a>.</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go"><span>I have my User ID but have lost/forgotten my Memorable Data and/or Password</span>
    <ul>
     <li>You can reset your Memorable Data and Password by clicking the "Password Reset" button on the login screen.</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go"><span>My account has been deactivated</span>
    <ul>
     <li>If your account has been deactivated then you will need to contact your local administrator, this is usually the person who set up your account.  If you don't have a local administrator or don't know who it is please <a href="#">Contact us</a>.</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="lst lst-b lst-ba icon-go"><span>My login attempt has failed</span>
    <ul>
     <li>If your login attempt has failed it could be because you have mistyped your User ID, Memorable Date and/or Password, sometimes it can be a combination of these, we advise you press the "Password Reset" button on the login page.</li>
     <li>If you do not receive an email with new details it could be that your account has been set up under an incorrect email address, if this is the case then please <a href="#">Contact us</a>.</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</article>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $('#expand').find('ul').hide();
 $('#expand').find('span').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change

```
$('#expand').find('span').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
});
```

to

```
$('#expand > li').click(function(e){
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you :) I'll accept the answer as soon as the time limit has finished :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#expand').on('click', 'li', function(e){
```